# Google App Engine Billing inconsistent with Usage History

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am sorry if this is not the right place to ask this question, but Google has moved customer support for Bronze Tier to Community Forum aka Stackoverflow... So here I am, stuck with a bill that I can't figure out. Just to give you the context, I am running an Android app sending videos averaging 2 megabytes per video to users. There are around 70 daily users downloading 2 videos a day.

Image here: http://postimg.org/image/cytlw3rzx/ (Sorry I don't have 10 reputation yet)

As you can see, there are supposedly 516 Gibibyte of Cloud Storage Download APAC. However, I only have around 150 megabytes of data stored on the cloud. So it is mathematically impossible to have such traffic over this period of time. On top of this, here is the Usage History which suggests totally different usage.

Image here: http://postimg.org/image/5h1tzl49f/

Please help if you have any idea what is going on as I am stuck with no customer support and no helpful information on the internet...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google's billing system, not programming.

Comment: Yes I understand, but as indicated, google has moved all customer support for Bronze Tier users to stackoverflow, there is simply no help out there. I don't know why you have to down vote my question, as I am a very new user of Stackoverflow, every single reputation means a lot to me. If this question is truely disturbing, I don't mind taking it off. However, I am only here because I am desperate for help...

Comment: Besides, there are also other Billing related question on the site. Perhaps due to 1) lack of support from google, 2) Legitimate question regarding Google Appengine

Comment: I'm well aware that Google and others have tried to move their support to [so]. However, [so] has its own rules about what is and is not on topic here. Google's billing system is off topic unless you can show that the problem arises from your code. As to downvotes: bad and off-topic questions frequently attract them. It's an indication that this isn't a useful question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage history you posted (your second picture) is only for the App Engine application, but does not include Cloud Storage usage. It also does not include any usage you may make of Compute Engine, Big Query etc.

That is why the usage history shows less than 1$ per day whereas your final bill shows additional charges for Cloud Storage.

You can ask billing-related questions to the Cloud Platform billing team here : https://support.google.com/code/contact/cloud_platform_billing

You can also find more info on your current usage here :

```
https://console.developers.google.com/project/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/billing/unbilledinvoice
```

If you have doubted about how your cloud storage buckets are used, [set up access logging as explained here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesslogs).

Comment: Thank you David! But the numbers from Cloud Storage Download APAC is still absurdly high... Do you have any idea what the reason might be?

Comment: It is hard to say like this. Are you sure you have less than 150MB on Cloud Storage ? I have added a link where you might find more info on your usage.

Comment: Yes I am sure of the amount of data on my Cloud Storage. Thanks for the additional link. It also indicates 500+ Gb of download. I have sent a help message via your first link last week and still waiting for reply. Meanwhile, the size of download is growing by 10Gb a day, which is impossible according to the number of users I have. I am seriously considering shutting down the app to stop the bleeding at this point.

Comment: Do you have public links that could be downloaded by people outside of your app ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. But I did share my source code with a freelancer earlier this month. Is it possible that he uses part of the code to download videos from the same source?

Comment: Only if you source code included Secrets from the Credentials section of the Developers' Console. With respect to your ticket, Billing questions may take some time to get answered.

Comment: I have address to the answer a link on how to setup access logging. You can use this to check who downloads files and how often.